# Vertical menu Orchard

Tags: menu, orchardcms

How should we create a vertical menu in orchard ? (menu ad left sidebar in below image)
The default menu widget is always horizontally oriented.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried modifying/overriding the css?  This horizontal behavior is just because the li elements are floated.

Comment: I have managed to change css via this way by creating a child theme.